# Pandas - Best way to set a column based on other columns in groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm having a hard time imagining a different way to do this in pandas. My way "works" but is incredibly slow. At a high level I want to do this:

1. Group data by a `id`, find the median value for `a`.
2. Find the difference between each value of `a` and its group's median
3. Find the max in a group of the median
4. Then, in the group, if `a` is missing/nan, overwrite/set `a` to the median if the value found in `step 3` is less than a tolerance (say 1).

This is how I've done it:

Assume a dataframe df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,2,2,3], 'a': [1, np.nan, 3, 1, 2], 'b': [np.nan, 6, 5, np.nan, 4], 'c': [4, 1, 2, 3, 3]})

    id   a    b  c
0   1  1.0  NaN  4
1   1  NaN  6.0  1
2   2  3.0  5.0  2
3   2  1.0  NaN  3
4   3  2.0  4.0  3
```

step 1:

```
df['median'] = df.groupby(['id'])['a'].transform('median')
```

step 2:

```
df['diff'] = abs(df['a'] - df['median'])
```

step 3:

```
df['diff'] = df.groupby(['id'])['diff'].transform('max')
```

step 4:

```
for key, g in df.groupby(['id']):
    index = (df.id == key) & (df['diff'] < 1.0) & (df.a.isna())
    if not df[index].empty:
        df.loc[index, 'a'] = g['median']
```

I'm relatively confident that steps 1-3 are correct and done in an efficient way (and hopefully in idomatic pandas). Step 4 I dislike, I'm pretty sure is the bottleneck, and it seems like the wrong way to do it. I can't figure out another way to do it.

Any suggestions in improving step 4 (and 1-3 if they are wrong/could be done a better way)?

EDIT: As you may have noticed, if you made it this far, this is just me trying to fill missing values in a specific way. If there is a much simpler way to do the whole thing, I'm all ears :)

Comment: Steps 1-3 are relatively good. I could be nitpicky but I don't think any changes would improve what you have by much

Comment: @RushabhMehta thanks for looking it over - what about 4 :D

Comment: step2: use `(df['a'] - df['median']).abs()`as this is vectorized

Comment: df.D = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.median())) almost does it, but doesn't deal with tolerances...

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 good catch! Thanks!

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1...both `abs` calls are vectorized just different functional form. Your suggestion inherits the numpy array call vs OP using Python built-in call. Marginal differences in performance if any.

Comment: @Parfati, thanks. I didn't know that python's built-in `abs` is that performant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the median column is already lined up with `'a'`, I don't think you need to loop at all, or even `groupby`.

```
df['a'] = df['median'].where(df['a'].isna() & (df['diff'] < 1), df['a'])
```

This will take the median where appropriate, otherwise just use `'a'`.

Comment: This doesn't work, he wants a unique median per group to be filled.

Comment: Since the median was calculated per group, each group's median is already lined up with the element(s) it would replace.

Comment: this does seem to work for my basic test case! Let me play with it a bit more to confirm. thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Consider also numpy's `where` for conditional logic across series/arrays. Replace loop with the following:

```
df['a'] = np.where((df['a'].isna()) & (df['diff'] < 1), df['median'], df['a'])
```

Comment: Is there a big difference between this on the response by BallpointBen? It looks like one is operating on a `series` and using pandas' `where` vs using numpy's where. I assume pandas uses `np.where` under the hood for its `where`

Comment: thanks - I tested this as well as the other, both worked and had similar performance. I'd accept both if I could